# Update Href of Link button Through Jquery

Tags: .net, jquery, redirect, href, linkbutton

I am using a link button to redirect the page to my desired location with some query string value from Jquery.
The Link Button code are as follows:

```
<td>
            <a id="selectAllLink" class="button" rel="nofollow ibox&width=800&height=400&title=Contact Now"
                href="#" onclick="return (this.href=='#');">Contact Selected</a>
        </td>
```

And the Jquery which will create/Update link on click event of my link button are as follows:

```
function CotactSelected() {
    var a = [];
    var n = $("td.title_listing input:checked");
    var s = "";
    n.each(function() {
        a.push($(this).val());
    });
    var s = a.join(',');

    if (s != null) {
        $("@.button#selectAllLink").attr("href", "/D_ContactSeller.aspx?property=" + s);

    }
    else {
        alert("Select atleast one property to contact!");
    }
}
```

What i wanted to do is it will collect all the comma separated value from check boxes and pass it to the another page with that collected value as query string.
On click of that Link Button it should carry all the comma separated values and redirected to the desired page.
Kindly help me..
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead of your function `CotactSelected`

```
$(function() {
  $('#selectAllLink').each(function() {
    var a = [];
    var n = $("td.title_listing input:checked");
    var s = "";

    n.each(function() {
      a.push(this.value);
    });
    s = a.join(',');

    if (a.length > 0)
      this.href= "/D_ContactSeller.aspx?property=" + s;
    else
      this.href = 'javascript:alert("Select at least one property to contact!");';
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to use Anchor Link Button Click event not location.href. 
So let me know whether is there easy solution is available or not?

Comment: I did some minor changes, how about now?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (s != null) {
  $("@.button#selectAllLink").attr("href", "");
  $("@.button#selectAllLink").attr("href", "/D_ContactSeller.aspx?property=" + s);
}
else {
    alert("Select atleast one property to contact!");
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was doing that only.
But it is still not working.
Is there something i am missing out?

Comment: please remove this code

onclick="return (this.href=='#');"

i think it cause a problem.

Comment: What should i try instead of onclick="return (this.href=='#');

Comment: when u click on this link first time then it will return true on click event,

after changing the href value when u click on link then your java script return (this.href=='#') will return false, so it won't work 
so try it

Comment: It's not working, actually the frame opens mentioning Loading... and no url changes. The problem is page is not redirected.